# Materialui - where to load CSS classes from?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

This might have a quick answer. I am starting to learn Material UI and want try its grid examples, but coding below mentions  that compilation rejects as NOTFOUND .. Could not locate a CSS file to load to try these examples.. Without the className parameter, i do not see any outline of the GRID, so may be these css 'classes.root' hold the formatting options. Appreciate your kind help,

```
function App() {
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>  ????
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
```

Comment: Its not clear from the code you've pasted whether `classes.root` is defined. Can you paste your entire App.js file?

Comment: app.js has nothing.. could not locate a CSS file to load for materialui grid

Comment: You have pasted half of a javascript file above. Please paste the whole file, as well as the exact error message that you're seeing.

Comment: @jmknoll  I had to post a new question since the comment does not allow to post the whole code..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662275/materialui-where-to-load-css-classes-from-part2

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `makeStyles`

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: props => props.color,
  },
});

function App(props) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      // ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: ```
import React from "react";
import MenuIcon from..

import {..
  Grid,
..
} from "@material-ui/core";

function Materialuig(){

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    color: (props) => props.color,
  },
});
    const classes = useStyles(props);
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
                </Grid>
        </div>
    );
}    
export default Materialuig;
```

Comment: Above is the code I am trying as per your advice, but getting errors 'Props not defined. 'paper' not defined. <Materialuig  /> is called from index.js

Comment: posting a new question since no space to post the whole code in comment section