# Materialui - where to load CSS classes from? part2

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, material-ui

I m starting to learn Material UI - Grid. This is a followup to the recent question I had asked
[Materialui - where to load CSS classes from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650170/materialui-where-to-load-css-classes-from?noredirect=1#comment110792391_62650170)
asking where to define the classes referenced by Material ui, namely classes.root

????
       
I modified the code as per a recommendation and now Compilation errors are as follows:
Failed to compile
./src/Materialuig.jsx
  Line 25:31:  'props' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 30:22:  'Paper' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
..

Here is the complete code:

```
import React from "react";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";

import {
  Button,
  Icon,
  makeStyles,
  Grid,
  IconButton,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";


function Materialuig(){

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    color: (props) => props.color,
  },
});
    const classes = useStyles(props);
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    );
}    
export default Materialuig;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Paper` component, but you aren't importing it, thus it is undefined.

You can import it in the same manner as `Grid` by adding it to your main [list of Material-UI imports](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-2):

```
import {
  Button,
  Icon,
  makeStyles,
  Grid,
  Paper,
  IconButton,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
```

or you can [import it as follows](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-1):

```
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
```

---

`props` is undefined because you aren't declaring it anywhere.
You need

```
function Materialuig(props){
```

instead of

```
function Materialuig(){
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks a lot for your response. A followup. 
Q.1.Why do we need props in function Materialuig(props){.. ? I am not passing any parameters when calling it?
Q.2. Why use props here?
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    color: (props) => props.color,
  },
});
    const classes = useStyles(props);
    return (

Comment: If you aren't passing any props to your component, then you shouldn't be passing `props` to `useStyles` and you shouldn't be trying to get `props.color` to set the color in your styles.